# How to download Azure snapshot

Tags: azure, windows-server-backup

Azure / cloud newbie here. We have an app that we have run on Azure for a few years. Company is winding down and I have been tasked with backing up and archiving the program and ideally the server config.
We have a GIT repo for the files but they want the server image saved if possible.
 I tried the file restore process but Powershell just keep closing when I run the script. I think because I ran it on a Windows 10 PC and not a Windows server 2012 machine. Which is what the VM is. 
Is there a possibly simpler method of downloading for archiving of a VM snapsHot in Azure?

Answer (score 3):

After you create a snapshot of the VM from the Azure console, click on the snapshot and click Export. It'll ask you to create a temporary download link and from there you can download the VHD.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I dont see that. When I am in the BACKUP "tab/section". I see the restore points. I dont actually see anything they call a Snapshot. I assumed the restore points are akin to Snapshots. There is no ability to right click. I only have the ability on the far right column to Restore vm, or start File Recovery which I cannot get to run on my local Win 10 PC[Screenshot of what I see][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMrMU.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "Export Disk" functionality

1. Locate the VM in the Azure Portal
2. Locate the disks for the VM
3. On each disk use "Export Disk" to get a download link

See the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/download-vhd?tabs=azure-portal)